# R median of columns with matching pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset looks like this

```
  rep_id  sex     activator   P16401d      P81605e      P7Z958d      B4DT29g
    CF9     Female  Control     808.3071    772.20756   14114.372   5516.857
    CF10    Female  Control     1332.5300   739.96297   19373.688   4855.419
    CF11    Female  Control     748.3975    1449.46860  17310.500   5324.638
    CF12    Female  Control     1271.5207   978.48424   6217.883    6015.900
    CF13    Female  Control     554.3564    461.37956   6659.669    5739.060
    CF14    Female  Control     1575.7039   1770.07244  7143.650    5936.352
```

I would like to use 'dplyr' to calculate the median of the columns that start with "P" and end with "d" **in each row**.
Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matches` and pass the regular expression to match the column names.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise(across(matches('^P.*d$'), median))

#   P16401d  P7Z958d
#1 1039.914 10629.01
```

To perform this calculation for each row use `rowwise` with `c_across` -

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = median(c_across(matches('^P.*d$')))) %>%
  ungroup

# rep_id sex    activator P16401d P81605e P7Z958d B4DT29g result
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 CF9    Female Control      808.    772.  14114.   5517.  7461.
#2 CF10   Female Control     1333.    740.  19374.   4855. 10353.
#3 CF11   Female Control      748.   1449.  17310.   5325.  9029.
#4 CF12   Female Control     1272.    978.   6218.   6016.  3745.
#5 CF13   Female Control      554.    461.   6660.   5739.  3607.
#6 CF14   Female Control     1576.   1770.   7144.   5936.  4360.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should clarify that I need the calculation by row. I added the note in the post

Comment: Edited the answer to perform the calculation rowwise.